# How to serialize a related object Django Rest Framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

```
class Flight(models.Model):
    field_1
    field_2
    field_3

class Approach(models.Model):
    flight_object(models.ForeignKey, 'Flight')
    approach_type
    number
```

Approach is related as an InlineFormset. How can I serialize Approach nested into Flight with the ability to create new approach objects. I'm unsure of the correct terminology which is making this more difficult to realize. My goal is to create a new Flight object with Approach as a related object in the FlightForm from a React Native project.[image]

Comment: can you  give us your expected serialized json format?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed the expected response json

```json
{
    "field_1": "value1",
    "field_2": "value2",
    "field_3": "value3",
    "approch_set": {
        "approach_type": "value",
        "number": 22
    }
}
```

for this expected result we will define two serializers.

```py
class ApproachSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Approach
        fields = ('approach_type', 'number', )

class FlightSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    approach_set = ApproachSerializer(many=true)
    class Meta:
        model = Flight
        fields = "__all__"
```

and in view class you can return `FlightSerializer` data like this.

```py
class FlightApiView(APIVIew):
    def get(self, request):
        flights = Flight.objects.all()
        return Response({'data': FlightSerializer(flights, many=True).data})
```

for more you can read [the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    approaches = SerializerMethodField(source='get_approaches')

def get_approaches(self, obj):
    approach_queryset = Approach.objects.filter(flight_object=obj.pk)
    return ApproachSerializer(approach_queryset, many=True).data
```

This is what finally worked, just want to come back and share it.

Thanks @shourav